# Optimizing the Django model for large tables

Tags: mysql, django

**Consider a bank with 1 million users and 1 billion transactions.**

Will all one billion transactions be placed in one table?

Is 1-2 billion records normal or too much?

If we want to see the transactions of a user, do we search this entire table every time?
Is this the way it works or is there a better way?

Comment: Usually with proper indexes, retrieval scales *O(log n)*, so the amount of transactions does not matter *that* much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we want to see the transactions of a user, do we search this entire table every time? Is this the way it works or is there a better way?

No, a database keeps *indexes*. Indexes allow searching in a database efficiently. For `ForeignKey`s, it makes indexes automatically.

The implementation of indexes depends on the database, but typically it is a tree-like structure like a B-tree, this means that we detect which rows to fetch in *O(log n)*, which thus does scale quite well with the number of records. The database thus has *not* to do a linear search.

If you want to retrieve the indexes of a user for the last *n* years, you typically make a composite index, so the model looks like:

```
from django.conf import settings


class Transaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['user', 'timestamp']),
        ]
```

This combines the `timestamp` and `user` fields in an index, making queries to retrieve the records for the last year for a given user usually quite efficient.

Databases are designed to try to retrieve data as efficient as possible, and thus will thus only as a last resort do a "linear scan" where the database has to enumerate over all records.

often however privacy rules require the bank to delete old records anyway. If I recall correctly, in the EU, banks are required to remove the transactions after a certain number of years (although they are required to keep these for a certain number of years as well).